# Getting variable from range slider javascript updated input?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, slider, range

I have a value being updated by an HTML range slider through javascript. I need to grab this number as a variable in javascript. How can I achieve this? Here's what I have so far.

```
<form class="daysAR"
<label for="days">Days</label><br />
<input type="range" min="0" max="31" value="15" id="days" step="1" oninput="accountsRecievableSlider(value)">
<output for="days" id="daysInAR">15</output>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function accountsRecievableSlider(AR) {
document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value = AR;
}
```

This is how I'm unsuccessfully trying to get the variable.

```
var selectday = document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value
document.write(selectday);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could please post a js fiddle demo

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the `form` tag.
try pasting this is an empty HTML:

```
<form class="daysAR">
    <label for="days">Days</label><br />
    <input type="range" min="0" max="31" value="15" id="days" step="1" oninput="accountsRecievableSlider(value)">
    <output for="days" id="daysInAR">15</output>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function accountsRecievableSlider(AR) {
    document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value = AR;
    var selectday = document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value
    console.log(selectday);
}
</script>
```

Worked for me

Comment: I'm sorry, what did I do wrong? Your example works for me, but the only difference I see is that you wrote it to the console. Regardless thanks.

Comment: I also closed the `form` tag and put your code inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on your browser console?

On this fiddle : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0kh9abk/1/) you can see an example.

```
window.accountsRecievableSlider = function() {
  document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value = document.querySelector('#days').value
}
```